# Apply several aggregate functions with one enumeration

Tags: f#, sequence

Let's assume I have a series of functions that work on a sequence, and I want to use them together in the following fashion:

```
let meanAndStandardDeviation data = 
    let m = mean data
    let sd = standardDeviation data
    (m, sd)
```

The code above is going to enumerate the sequence twice. I am interested in a function that will give the same result but enumerate the sequence only once. This function will be something like this:

```
magicFunction (mean, standardDeviation) data
```

where the input is a tuple of functions and a sequence and the ouput is the same with the function above.

Is this possible if the functions `mean` and `stadardDeviation` are black boxes and I cannot change their implementation?

If I wrote `mean` and `standardDeviation` myself, is there a way to make them work together? Maybe somehow making them keep yielding the input to the next function and hand over the result when they are done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this using just a single iteration when the functions are black boxes is to use the `Seq.cache` function (which evaluates the sequence once and stores the results in memory) or to convert the sequence to other in-memory representation.

When a function takes `seq<T>` as an argument, you don't even have a guarantee that it will evaluate it just once - and usual implementations of standard deviation would first calculate the average and then iterate over the sequence again to calculate the squares of errors.

I'm not sure if you can calculate standard deviation with just a single pass. However, it is possible to do that if the functions are expressed using `fold`. For example, calculating maximum and average using two passes looks like this:

```
let maxv = Seq.fold max Int32.MinValue input
let minv = Seq.fold min Int32.MaxValue input
```

You can do that using a single pass like this:

```
Seq.fold (fun (s1, s2) v -> 
  (max s1 v, min s2 v)) (Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue) input
```

The lambda function is a bit ugly, but you can define a combinator to compose two functions:

```
let par f g (i, j) v = (f i v, g j v)
Seq.fold (par max min) (Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue) input
```

This approach works for functions that can be defined using `fold`, which means that they consist of some initial value (`Int32.MinValue` in the first example) and then some function that is used to update the initial (previous) state when it gets the next value (and then possibly some post-processing of the result). In general, it should be possible to rewrite single-pass functions in this style, but I'm not sure if this can be done for standard deviation. It can be definitely done for mean:

```
let (count, sum) = Seq.fold (fun (count, sum) v -> 
  (count + 1.0, sum + v)) (0.0, 0.0) input
let mean = sum / count
```

Comment: It is in fact possible to calculate the standard deviation using a `fold` - it uses the definition of the variance - see for example http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.02/carlos1.html

Comment: "I'm not sure if you can calculate standard deviation with just a single pass". See Knuth's Bible!

Comment: @JonHarrop The problem with Knith's Bible is that you can't fit it in the 20kg baggage allowance if you're flying with easyJet....

Answer (score 2):

What we're talking about here is a function with the following signature:

`(seq<'a> -> 'b) * (seq<'a> -> 'c) -> seq<'a> -> ('b * 'c)`

There is no straightforward way that I can think of that will achieve the above using a single iteration of the sequence if that is the signature of the functions. Well, no way that is more efficient than:

```
let magicFunc (f1:seq<'a>->'b, f2:seq<'a>->'c) (s:seq<'a>) = 
    let cached = s |> Seq.cache
    (f1 cached, f2 cached)
```

That ensures a single iteration of the sequence itself (perhaps there are side effects, or it's slow), but does so by essentially caching the results. The cache is still iterated another time. Is there anything wrong with that? What are you trying to achieve?